# could not invoke kubernetes service by internal endpont

Tags: kubernetes

I want to invoke service in my kuberetes cluster, so I try to invoke servcie(the backend pod deployment by deplyment) like this:

```
curl http://soa-illidan-hub-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:11024
```

it tell me `curl: (7) Failed to connect to soa-illidan-hub-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local port 11024: Host is unreachable`, and I am ping:

```
/ # ping soa-illidan-hub-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local
PING soa-illidan-hub-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local (10.254.42.62): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.254.42.62: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 10.254.42.62: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 10.254.42.62: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
```

why the curl tell me host is unreachable? and. I could using endpoint ip to invoke servcie,should I using ip? using servcie ip is a good practice?

Comment: Are both curl and ping commands executed inside a pod (using `kubectl exec` command)?

Comment: yes. inside the same pod.@Lukman

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
wget -qO- http://soa-illidan-hub-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local
```

or try directly to pod ip

```
wget -qO- POD_IP:PORT
```

Comment: using the service name is the best, the service ip could change. your command is also helpful.@Dashrath Mundkar

Comment: @Dolphin Yes I know. but for debugging purpose it's good to hit endpoint by using IP.

Answer (score 1):

I finnally find the reason, the pod's running node kube-proxy stopped. Try to start kube-proxy will fix this, in my centos 7.6 start like this:

```
systemctl start kube-proxy
```